# Search in nested list

Tags: c#, linq, list, nested

I have one `List<List<Data>>` with some `List<Data>` wich is filled in a foreach-loop. So before I create a new `List<Data>`, I need to check, if some values already exist in any `List<Data>` in `List<List<Data>>`. If so, I need to return this list, to add the Data in this `List<Data>.`

```
private List<List<DataToShow>> listList;
private List<DataToShow> list;

private void sortTestData()
{
     listList = new List<List<DataToShow>>();

     foreach (DataToShow data in dataPack)
     {
         List<DataToShow> list = new List<DataToShow> { data };

            if (listList.Count != 0)
                checkModusStatus(data);

            listList.Add(list);
        }
    }

    private void checkModusStatus(DataToShow data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listList.Count; i++)
        {
            var value = listList[i].Where(x => (x.Mode == data.Mode) && (x.State == data.State));
        }
```

}

So I always get null, although there are same entries

Any ideas beside two foreach Loops?

Comment: do you need only the first item matching the conditions?

Comment: Yes, the first match. There can only be one "first" match - if there would be anouther, the first search failed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check whether any list in a list of lists matches predicate

Yes, you can check whether any list in your list of lists already contains an equivalent instance of the `DataToShow` you are thinking of adding like this:

```
bool equivalentInstancePresent = listList.Any(dataList => dataList.Any(data => IsEquivalentInstance(data));

private bool IsEquivalentInstance(DataToShow data)
{
    // your check here
}
```

Using `Any(predicate)` will iterate over the respective `IEnumerable` and return `true` as soon as an element is found that matches the predicate. Otherwise it will return `false` after iteration is completed.

A shorter version of the same linq expression:

```
bool equivalentInstancePresent = listList.Any(dataList => dataList.Any(IsEquivalentInstance);
```

## Get first list in a list of list that matches predicate

If you also need to return the list containing an equivalent instance – as stated in your question – you can use the following expression

```
List<DataToShow> listWithEquivalentInstancePresent = listList.FirstOrDefault(dataList => dataList.Any(IsEquivalentInstance));
```

---

As asked in the comments, you can also modify the predicate to limit witch items in each list to check. Note: I use a separate variable for the predicates in the following examples.

## Modify predicate to only check first x-th items

If you want to limit your search scope to the first 5 items in each list:

```
Func<IEnumerable<DataToShow>, bool> firstFiveItemsContainEquivalentInstance = (dataList) => dataList.Take(5).Any(IsEquivalentInstance);
var listWhereFirstFiveItemsContainEquivalentInstance = listOfLists.FirstOrDefault(firstFiveItemsContainEquivalentInstance);
```

## Modify predicate to only check x-th item in each list

Checking only the first item is relativly simple, as seen below.

```
Func<IEnumerable<DataToShow>, bool> firstItemIsEquivalent = (dataList) => IsEquivalentInstance(dataList.FirstOrDefault());
var listWhereFirstItemIsEquivalentInstance = listOfLists.FirstOrDefault(firstItemIsEquivalent);
```

The predicate to check only the second item in each list looks as follows

```
Func<IEnumerable<DataToShow>, bool> secondItemIsEquivalent = (dataList) => IsEquivalentInstance(dataList.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault());
```

Comment: Is it possible only to search in the first item of the list? Having thousands of items in each index affects the Performance..

Answer (score 0):

For your DataToShow, you need to override the Equals method

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;
    DataToShow x = obj as DataToShow;
    if (x == null) return false;
    else return (x.Mode == this.Mode) && (x.State == this.State);
}
```

Now you can use the Contains method defined for collections

```
foreach (List<Data> innerlist in listlist) {
    if(innerlist.Contains(data))
        return innerlist;
    return Null;
}
```

Call this function for each data in datapack.